# Slow Search Queries - Bad coding, (LEFT JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, search

Bad search queries are crashing our site. The person who wrote the counted every single subcategory and then added them together to get the total of main categories.
For paging Next, Last, Pages and then the queries are written with JOIN/ INNER JOIN (of all products of that page). It's creating too many steps and thus slowing everything down until it times out. Help!

Query abstract:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT node.nid) AS cnt FROM 
content_type_product cp 
LEFT JOIN node node ON node.nid = cp.nid 
LEFT JOIN uc_products uc_products ON node.nid = uc_products.nid 
LEFT JOIN users users ON users.uid = node.uid 
LEFT JOIN files ON files.fid = cp.field_product_image_1_value 
LEFT JOIN content_type_product_tags ct ON ct.field_product_product_id_value = cp.nid 
WHERE 
    (
    node.status <> N
    ) 
AND 
    (
    ct.field_product_tag_id_value = N
    ) 
AND 
    (
    cp.field_deleted_value <> N
    ) 
AND 
    (
    cp.field_stock_level_value > N
    ) 
AND EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT scp.nid FROM content_type_store scp 
    LEFT JOIN node snode ON snode.nid = scp.nid 
    LEFT JOIN users susers ON susers.uid = snode.uid 
    WHERE susers.name = users.name 
        AND scp.field_shop_activated_value = 'S' 
        AND scp.field_shop_suspended_value = 'S') 
ORDER BY cp.field_product_last_changed_value DESC;
```

Query sample:

```
SELECT count(Distinct node.nid) as cnt 
FROM content_type_product cp 
LEFT JOIN node node ON node.nid = cp.nid 
LEFT JOIN uc_products uc_products ON node.nid = uc_products.nid 
LEFT JOIN users users ON users.uid = node.uid 
LEFT JOIN files ON files.fid = cp.field_product_image_1_value 
LEFT JOIN content_type_product_tags ct ON ct.field_product_product_id_value = cp.nid
WHERE 
    (
    node.status <> 0
    ) 
    AND 
        (
        ct.field_product_tag_id_value = 478
        ) 
    AND 
        (
        cp.field_deleted_value <> 1
        ) 
    AND 
        (
        cp.field_stock_level_value > 0
        ) 
    AND EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT scp.nid FROM content_type_store scp 
        LEFT JOIN node snode on snode.nid = scp.nid 
        LEFT JOIN users susers on susers.uid = snode.uid 
        WHERE susers.name = users.name 
            AND scp.field_shop_activated_value = '1' 
            AND scp.field_shop_suspended_value = '0'
        ) 
    ORDER BY cp.field_product_last_changed_value DESC
```

Comment: I'd suggest starting over with a flowchart on a piece of paper.
First write down what data you need to display on the page.
Then write down from which relevant tables this needs to be taken.
Then make a flow chart so you understand what is taken when and then build a query on that basis.
When you take this approach you can make a complex query, without losing track what does what.

Comment: You'll get help more readily if you format the queries properly so they're more readable.

Comment: As a little extra hint your `order by` appears to be useless; you're using an analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes in main table and joined tables will fasten your query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the following steps need to follow to avoid slow query

1. First start from node instead of starting from content table.
2. For content table join with `vid` instead of `nid`
3. No need to use `distinct` and `group by` in query. If you are using that your query has  some join problem.

```sql
SELECT count(Distinct node.nid) as cnt 
FROM node node 
LEFT JOIN content_type_product cp ON cp.vid = node.vid 
LEFT JOIN uc_products uc_products ON node.vid = uc_products.vid 
LEFT JOIN users users ON users.uid = node.uid 
LEFT JOIN files ON files.fid = cp.field_product_image_1_value 
LEFT JOIN content_type_product_tags ct ON ct.field_product_product_id_value = cp.vid
WHERE 
    (
    node.status <> 0
    ) 
    AND 
        (
        ct.field_product_tag_id_value = 478
        ) 
    AND 
        (
        cp.field_deleted_value <> 1
        ) 
    AND 
        (
        cp.field_stock_level_value > 0
        ) 
    AND EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT scp.nid FROM content_type_store scp 
        LEFT JOIN node snode on snode.nid = scp.nid 
        LEFT JOIN users susers on susers.uid = snode.uid 
        WHERE susers.name = users.name 
            AND scp.field_shop_activated_value = '1' 
            AND scp.field_shop_suspended_value = '0'
        ) 
    ORDER BY cp.field_product_last_changed_value DESC
```